# Apache Zeppelin Spark Interpreter Variable Scope Issue

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Is there a way to control scope of variables declared in a Note using Spark Interpreter? 
As of now able to access a variable declared in one Note from another Note

Answer (score 0):

Probably Not Possible
Single SparkIMain and SparkILoop instance is shared across all Note